# Retain values in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Consider the following Pandas Dataframe:

```
_df = pd.DataFrame([
    [4.0, "Diastolic Blood Pressure", 1.0, "2017-01-15", 68],
    [4.0, "Diastolic Blood Pressure", 5.0, "2017-04-15", 60],
    [4.0, "Diastolic Blood Pressure", 8.0, "2017-06-18", 68],
    [4.0, "Heart Rate", 1.0, "2017-01-15", 85],
    [4.0, "Heart Rate", 5.0, "2017-04-15", 72],
    [4.0, "Heart Rate", 8.0, "2017-06-18", 81],
    [6.0, "Diastolic Blood Pressure", 1.0, "2017-01-18", 114],
    [6.0, "Diastolic Blood Pressure", 6.0, "2017-02-18", 104],
    [6.0, "Diastolic Blood Pressure", 9.0, "2017-03-18", 124]
    ], columns = ['ID', 'VSname', 'Visit', 'VSdate', 'VSres'])
```

I'd like to create the 'Flag' variable in this df: for each ID and VSName, show the difference from baseline (visit 1) at each visit.

[image]

I tried different approaches and I'm stuck.

I come from a background of SAS programming, and that'd be very easy in SAS to retain values from a row to another, and then substract. I'm sure my mind is poluted by SAS (and the title is clearly wrong), but this has to be doable with Pandas, one way or another. Any idea?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Comment: please do not put data as images , users cannot copy them and so cannot reproduce the question

Comment: thanks anky_91. Good point. I added code to reproduce data.

Comment: The data added is a tad different than the image, however added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the DataFrame is ordered by id and visit group (i.e. the 5, 8 and directly after the 1), you can use cumcount:

```
c = (df.visit == 1).cumcount()
```

You can subtract VSRes from the first VSRes entry of each group:

```
df.VSRes - df.groupby(c).VSRes.transform("first")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers kindly given, none worked, got errors I coudln't fix. Not sure why... I managed to produced something close using the following:

```
baseline = df[df["Visit"] ==  1.0]
baseline = baseline.rename(columns={'VSres': 'baseline'})
df = pd.merge(df, baseline, on = ["ID", "VSname"], how='left')
df["chg"] = df["VSres"] - df["baseline"]
```

That's not very beautiful, I know...